# Will the topbar be added to the old User Profile page?

Tags: support, profile-page, top-bar

I use the following page as my 'home page' for Stack Exchange https://stackexchange.com/users/45534/affable-geek?tab=accounts

I believe this is the user profile page - but in any case, it seems to be a good page for people to link to when they want to know about my over SE "creds."

My question is this - is the new topbar scheduled to go to that page, or is this profile page heading towards deprecation?  If it is scheduled to go, what is the ETA? (Not pushing the schedule, just curious what it would be.)